# Centrar svg dentro de um elemento <rect>

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Bom dia, 
Eu tenho o seguinte código

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 708.7 708.7" style="enable-background:new 0 0 708.7 708.7;" xml:space="preserve">
<rect x="352.9" y="352.9" width="2.8" height="2.8"/>
<rect class="st0" width="708.7" height="708.7"/>
</svg>`

O objetivo seria usar este ficheiro e retirar as coordenadas `x` e `y` do primeiro elemento `rect` e posicionar lá o seguinte `código svg`:

`<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="86.129525" y="118.129525" viewBox="0 0 352.9 352.9" style="enable-background:new 0 0 226.8 340.2;" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="none" height="472.44095000000004">
<g id="firstG">
    <path id="g01" d="M66.8,257.7c-1.1,0.9-2.2,2.4-3.9,2c-1.4-0.3-2.1-1.4-2.5-2.7c-0.4-1.1-0.7-2.3,0.2-3.3c0.8-0.9,2.2-1.2,3.4-1.3   c1.4-0.1,2.5,0,2.8,1.6c0.1,0.6,0.1,1.1,0.6,1.5c0.5,0.5,1.3,0.8,1.9,1.2c2.8,2.1,5.8,3.5,9.2,4.5c-0.7-1.6-1.3-3.1-2-4.7   c-0.1-0.3-0.3-1.1-0.5-1.2c-0.1-0.1-0.6,0.1-0.8,0c-0.5,0-0.9-0.3-1.3-0.6c-0.6-0.6-1.3-1.8-1.5-2.6c-0.5-1.6,1.2-1.2,2.1-1   c0.2-2.1,2.2-6.3,5-4.5c1.2,0.8,1.4,2.4,1.1,3.7c-0.1,0.7-0.4,1.4-0.8,2c-0.4,0.6-1.1,1-1.5,1.5c-0.8,1.1,0.9,2.9,1.4,3.9   c0.4,0.7,0.9,1.5,1,2.2c0.1,0.3,0.1,0.6,0.1,1c0.1,0.7,0,0.8,0.7,0.9c3.7,0.5,7.3,1.1,11,1.5c4,0.5,8.1,1.2,12.2,0.8   c-1.1-1.8-2.1-3.6-3.3-5.3c-0.5-0.7-0.7-0.6-1.5-0.4c-0.7,0.1-1.2-0.1-1.8-0.5c-0.5-0.4-1.1-1-1.3-1.7c-0.2-0.8,0.3-1.9,0.6-2.8   c0.6-1.6,1.4-3,3.2-3.3c1.4-0.2,3.3,0.2,4.2,1.4c1,1.5,0.2,3.2-0.7,4.5c-0.3,0.4-0.6,0.8-0.9,1.1c-0.1,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.4,0.5   c-0.4,0.7-0.2,0.1-0.1,0.6c0.3,0.8,1.3,1.8,1.8,2.5c0.5,0.7,1.2,1.4,1.5,2.2c0.3,0.7,0.4,1.1,1.2,1.3c1.1,0.2,2.4,0,3.4,0   c1.3,0,2.5,0,3.8-0.1c2.4,0,4.8-0.1,7.1-0.1c-0.9-1.4-1.8-3.3-3.1-4.5c-1-1-2.7-0.5-4-0.9c-1.4-0.4-2.5-1.6-2.4-3.1   c0.2-1.8,1.8-2.4,3.4-2.6c1.6-0.3,3.4-0.4,4.3,1.2c0.4,0.7,0.5,1.3,0.3,2c-0.2,0.6-1.2,1.8-1,2.4c0.2,0.7,1.4,1.5,1.9,2   c0.7,0.7,1.3,1.4,2.1,2.1c0.5,0.4,1.2,1.1,1.9,1.3c1,0.3,2.3,0.1,3.3,0.1c2.1,0,4.2-0.1,6.2-0.5c0.8-0.1,1.7-0.4,2.5-0.6   c0.6-0.1,0.6-0.1,0.8,0.4c0.1,0.4,0.3,0.8,0.2,1.2c-0.1,0.7-0.7,0.8-1.3,0.9c-1.1,0.1-2.2,0.1-3.3,0.1c-2.1,0.1-4.3,0.2-6.4,0.3   c-2.2,0.1-4.6,0-6.7,0.3c-0.9,0.1-0.9,0.5-1.3,1.3c-0.4,0.8-0.9,1.5-1.5,2.1c-0.5,0.5-1.3,1.1-1.6,1.7c-0.4,0.8-0.2,2.2-0.2,3.1   c-0.1,1.6-0.7,2.8-2.1,3.8c-1.2,0.9-2.6,0.7-3.9,0.1c-1.2-0.6-2.6-2.5-1.9-3.9c0.4-0.9,1.4-1.6,2.3-2.1c0.9-0.5,1.8-0.6,2.7-1   c0.9-0.4,1.7-1.4,2.4-2.1c0.9-0.9,1.6-1.8,2.3-2.8c-4.3-0.1-8.6-0.2-12.9-0.4c-2.1-0.1-4.2-0.1-6.4-0.2c-0.5,0-1.1-0.1-1.5,0   c-0.6,0.1-0.7,0.3-1.1,0.8c-0.6,0.8-1.2,1.6-1.8,2.3c-1,1.2-2.4,1.9-2.7,3.6c-0.1,0.6,0,1.1-0.4,1.7c-0.4,0.6-1,1-1.7,1.3   c-1.5,0.7-3,0.3-4.2-0.7c-1-0.8-1.6-1.9-0.7-3c1.1-1.4,3.3-2.7,5.1-2.5c1.1,0.1,1.5-0.6,2.2-1.4c0.8-0.8,1.6-1.7,2.4-2.5   c-3.4-0.6-7-0.5-10.4-1.2c-0.7-0.1-1.4-0.5-2.2-0.4c-0.8,0.1-1.6,0.7-2.3,1.1c-1.3,0.8-2.7,1.4-2.7,3.1c-0.1,2.6-2.1,4.1-4.6,3.4   c-1.2-0.3-2.5-0.4-2.9-1.7c-0.3-1,0-2.3,0.7-3.1c1-1.2,2.8-1.4,4.3-1.5c0.9-0.1,1.7,0.1,2.5-0.3c0.8-0.4,1.5-1.1,2.2-1.7   C74.3,262.9,70.6,260.2,66.8,257.7z M101,252.5c-2.9,0-3,4.4,0.1,3.8c1-0.2,2-1,2.1-2C103.4,253,102.1,252.5,101,252.5z M61.4,256   c0,0.9,0.5,2.5,1.6,2.1c0.9-0.3,1.7-1.4,1.6-2.3c0-1.1-1-1.5-1.9-1.5C61.8,254.4,61.4,255.1,61.4,256z M116.5,257.4   c0.8,0,2.1-0.2,1.7-1.3c-0.3-1-1.5-1.3-2.5-1.3c-0.9,0-2.1,0.4-1.6,1.6C114.5,257.4,115.6,257.3,116.5,257.4z M70.4,268.3   c0.8,0.6,1.8,1.6,2.9,1.7c1.1,0.1,1.6-0.6,1.3-1.6C74.1,266.8,70.9,266.6,70.4,268.3z M75.5,252.8c0.8,0.9,1.1,0.3,1.7-0.4   c0.7-0.9,1.4-1.7,0.8-2.8c-0.3-0.5-0.5-0.9-1-0.6c-0.4,0.2-0.6,0.6-0.7,0.9C75.9,250.7,75.8,251.8,75.5,252.8z M109.4,275.2   c0.6,0.6,1.3,1.4,2.2,1.5c0.8,0.1,1.9-0.4,2-1.3C113.8,273.3,110.2,274.5,109.4,275.2z M88.2,273.9c0.5-0.2,0.4-0.3,0.4-0.8   c0-0.3,0-0.5-0.2-0.8c-0.6-0.7-1.6-0.3-2.1,0.2C86.9,273,87.6,273.4,88.2,273.9z" />
</g>
<g id="secondG">
    <g id="thirdG">
    <path d="M0.88-13.57L0.88-13.57L2.98-13.69Q3.99-16.59 5.82-19.40Q7.64-22.22 9.95-24.44Q12.26-26.67 14.85-28.04Q17.43-29.40 19.99-29.40L19.99-29.40Q20.96-29.40 21.99-28.94Q23.02-28.48 23.73-27.55Q24.44-26.63 24.68-25.22Q24.91-23.81 24.23-21.92L24.23-21.92Q24.02-21.34 23.48-21.08Q22.93-20.83 22.24-20.83Q21.55-20.83 20.87-21.04Q20.20-21.25 19.74-21.57Q19.28-21.88 19.15-22.24Q19.03-22.60 19.49-22.89L19.49-22.89Q20.12-23.31 20.60-24.05Q21.08-24.78 21.25-25.49Q21.42-26.21 21.11-26.73Q20.79-27.26 19.78-27.26L19.78-27.26Q18.98-27.26 17.75-26.12Q16.51-24.99 15.12-23.14Q13.73-21.29 12.35-18.94Q10.96-16.59 9.95-14.20L9.95-14.20L19.28-14.83Q19.78-14.83 20.08-14.51Q20.37-14.20 20.39-13.82Q20.41-13.44 20.20-13.10Q19.99-12.77 19.49-12.73L19.49-12.73L8.90-11.42Q8.27-9.53 8.09-7.85Q7.90-6.17 8.27-4.91Q8.65-3.65 9.68-2.90Q10.71-2.14 12.60-2.14L12.60-2.14Q13.73-2.14 15.16-2.52Q16.59-2.90 18.33-3.86Q20.08-4.83 22.18-6.49Q24.28-8.15 26.75-10.67L26.75-10.67Q27.09-11.00 27.49-11.00Q27.89-11.00 28.22-10.71L28.22-10.71Q28.56-10.37 28.56-9.95Q28.56-9.53 28.27-9.20L28.27-9.20Q26.42-7.35 24.74-5.78Q23.06-4.20 21.27-3.00Q19.49-1.81 17.51-1.05Q15.54-0.29 13.15-0.04L13.15-0.04Q9.58 0.21 7.27-0.57Q4.96-1.34 3.65-2.81Q2.35-4.28 2.02-6.30Q1.68-8.32 2.10-10.63L2.10-10.63L1.05-10.50Q0.59-10.54 0.32-11.03Q0.04-11.51 0-12.03Q-0.04-12.56 0.17-13.02Q0.38-13.48 0.88-13.57ZM30.07 0.04L30.07 0.04Q28.43 0.04 27.55-1.30L27.55-1.30Q27.05-2.02 26.80-3.40Q26.54-4.79 26.52-6.47Q26.50-8.15 26.69-10.02Q26.88-11.89 27.24-13.57Q27.59-15.25 28.10-16.61Q28.60-17.98 29.19-18.69L29.19-18.69Q30.41-20.12 31.77-20.54Q33.14-20.96 34.21-20.81Q35.28-20.66 35.83-20.16Q36.37-19.66 35.87-19.24L35.87-19.24Q35.66-19.07 35.26-17.83Q34.86-16.59 34.42-14.85Q33.98-13.10 33.58-11.11Q33.18-9.11 33.03-7.41Q32.89-5.71 33.05-4.60Q33.22-3.49 33.89-3.49L33.89-3.49Q35.03-3.49 36.33-4.81Q37.63-6.13 38.85-8.06Q40.07-10.00 41.03-12.20Q42-14.41 42.42-16.21L42.42-16.21Q42.63-17.14 42.71-17.89Q42.80-18.65 42.67-19.11Q42.55-19.57 42.17-19.72Q41.79-19.87 41.12-19.53L41.12-19.53Q40.57-19.28 40.24-19.93Q39.90-20.58 39.90-21.48Q39.90-22.39 40.34-23.16Q40.78-23.94 41.79-23.94L41.79-23.94Q42.88-23.94 43.51-23.42Q44.14-22.89 44.44-22.09Q44.73-21.29 44.79-20.39Q44.86-19.49 44.86-18.73L44.86-18.73Q44.86-17.51 44.56-16.09Q44.27-14.66 43.72-13.15Q43.18-11.63 42.40-10.08Q41.62-8.53 40.66-7.14L40.66-7.14Q38.26-3.65 35.64-1.81Q33.01 0.04 30.07 0.04ZM48.85 0L48.85 0Q47.25 0 46.12-0.99Q44.98-1.97 44.60-3.40L44.60-3.40Q43.97-5.71 44.86-8.90L44.86-8.90Q45.57-11.51 47.00-13.84Q48.43-16.17 50.44-17.98L50.44-17.98Q52.33-19.74 54.16-20.50Q55.99-21.25 57.33-20.92L57.33-20.92Q58.04-20.71 58.59-20.22Q59.14-19.74 59.35-19.11L59.35-19.11Q59.85-17.81 59.39-15.83L59.39-15.83Q59.30-15.37 58.95-15.16Q58.59-14.95 58.17-15.04L58.17-15.04Q57.71-15.12 57.48-15.48Q57.25-15.83 57.33-16.25L57.33-16.25Q57.41-16.55 57.50-17.07Q57.58-17.60 57.25-17.60L57.25-17.60Q56.66-17.60 55.80-16.74Q54.94-15.88 54.03-14.55Q53.13-13.23 52.33-11.57Q51.53-9.91 51.07-8.36L51.07-8.36Q50.74-7.22 50.61-6.09Q50.48-4.96 50.63-4.20Q50.78-3.44 51.30-3.26Q51.83-3.07 52.79-3.91L52.79-3.91Q53.93-4.87 55.48-6.80Q57.04-8.74 58.67-12.14L58.67-12.14Q58.72-12.35 58.88-12.68L58.88-12.68Q58.97-12.89 59.05-13.04Q59.14-13.19 59.22-13.36L59.22-13.36L59.35-13.52Q60.19-14.66 61.42-14.93Q62.66-15.20 63.76-15.04Q64.85-14.87 65.52-14.45Q66.19-14.03 65.90-13.73L65.90-13.73Q65.60-13.44 65.29-12.58Q64.97-11.72 64.70-10.63Q64.43-9.53 64.26-8.34Q64.09-7.14 64.07-6.13Q64.05-5.12 64.20-4.47Q64.34-3.82 64.72-3.82L64.72-3.82Q65.06-3.82 65.41-4.05Q65.77-4.28 66.09-4.60Q66.40-4.91 66.67-5.27Q66.95-5.63 67.16-5.84L67.16-5.84Q67.87-6.68 68.50-7.50Q69.13-8.32 69.57-8.97Q70.01-9.62 70.29-10.04Q70.56-10.46 70.56-10.46L70.56-10.46Q70.77-10.84 71.19-10.94Q71.61-11.05 71.99-10.79L71.99-10.79Q72.37-10.58 72.47-10.16Q72.58-9.74 72.37-9.37L72.37-9.37Q72.32-9.32 72.05-8.90Q71.78-8.48 71.30-7.79Q70.81-7.10 70.16-6.24Q69.51-5.38 68.75-4.49L68.75-4.49Q64.85 0 61.78 0L61.78 0Q60.77 0 59.93-0.46Q59.09-0.92 58.63-1.72L58.63-1.72Q58.17-2.44 57.96-3.72Q57.75-5.00 57.79-6.51L57.79-6.51Q56.83-5.17 55.78-3.99Q54.73-2.81 53.59-1.93Q52.46-1.05 51.26-0.53Q50.06 0 48.85 0Z" transform="translate(56.70000457763672, 145)" /></g>
    <path id="g18" d="M117.8,166.6c0,0.4-0.2,0.9-0.6,1.5c-0.4,0.6-0.9,1.2-1.5,1.9c-0.6,0.7-1.2,1.3-1.9,1.9c-0.7,0.6-1.2,1.1-1.7,1.5   c0.4,0.6,0.7,1.1,0.9,1.5c0.2,0.4,0.3,0.6,0.4,0.6c0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.5c0,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.3,0.5c-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.1   c-0.2,0-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.3c0,0-0.1-0.2-0.4-0.6c-0.2-0.3-0.5-0.8-0.8-1.3c0,0-0.1,0-0.1,0c0,0,0,0-0.1,0c-1,0.7-1.9,1.2-2.8,1.6   c-0.9,0.4-1.8,0.6-2.6,0.6h-0.1c-1.1,0-1.9-0.4-2.4-1.1c-0.5-0.6-0.6-1.4-0.4-2.4c0.2-0.8,0.5-1.6,1.1-2.6c0.4-0.8,0.9-1.6,1.5-2.4   c0.6-0.8,1.2-1.6,1.9-2.5c-0.6-2.2-0.7-4-0.3-5.4c0.2-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.6-1.4c0.3-0.4,0.6-0.8,0.9-1.1c0.4-0.4,0.9-0.7,1.4-0.9   c0.6-0.2,1.1-0.4,1.7-0.4c0.6,0,1.2,0,1.7,0.2c0.6,0.2,1,0.5,1.4,1c0.5,0.5,0.7,1.2,0.7,1.9c0,0.8-0.3,1.6-0.8,2.4   c-0.4,0.6-0.9,1.3-1.4,2c-0.5,0.7-1.1,1.4-1.6,2.1c-0.7,0.8-1.3,1.7-1.9,2.5c0.1,0.3,0.3,0.7,0.5,1.1c0.2,0.4,0.4,0.9,0.6,1.2   s0.4,0.8,0.6,1.2c0.4-0.4,0.8-0.8,1.2-1.3s0.8-1,1.1-1.5c0.3-0.5,0.6-1,0.8-1.6c0.2-0.5,0.3-1.1,0.3-1.6c0-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.5-0.4   c0.3-0.1,0.7-0.1,1,0c0.4,0.1,0.7,0.2,1,0.3C117.6,166.2,117.8,166.4,117.8,166.6z M107.7,171.5c-0.6,1.1-1,1.9-1,2.4   s0.1,0.8,0.4,0.8c0.3,0,0.8-0.1,1.3-0.4s1.2-0.7,1.9-1.3c-0.3-0.5-0.6-1-0.9-1.5c-0.3-0.5-0.5-1.1-0.7-1.6   c-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.6-0.5,0.8C108,171,107.8,171.3,107.7,171.5z M108.1,160.7c-0.3,1-0.3,2.2,0.1,3.6c0.5-0.6,1-1.2,1.4-1.8   c0.4-0.6,0.8-1.1,1.2-1.7c0.4-0.7,0.7-1.2,0.7-1.6c0.1-0.4,0-0.7-0.2-0.8c-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.2-0.7-0.2c-0.3,0-0.7,0.2-1,0.4   c-0.3,0.2-0.6,0.5-0.9,0.9C108.4,159.9,108.2,160.3,108.1,160.7z" />
    <g id="fourdG">
    <path d="M19.95 0L19.95 0Q18.77 0.08 17.77-0.23Q16.76-0.55 16.00-1.20Q15.25-1.85 14.83-2.77Q14.41-3.70 14.41-4.83L14.41-4.83Q14.41-5.33 14.89-5.61Q15.37-5.88 15.96-5.90Q16.55-5.92 17.03-5.69Q17.51-5.46 17.51-4.96L17.51-4.96Q17.51-4.07 17.72-3.51Q17.93-2.94 18.25-2.63Q18.56-2.31 18.94-2.21Q19.32-2.10 19.70-2.10L19.70-2.10Q21.08-2.10 22.39-3.15Q23.69-4.20 24.72-5.92Q25.75-7.64 26.42-9.85Q27.09-12.05 27.20-14.36Q27.30-16.67 26.78-18.88Q26.25-21.08 24.91-22.81Q23.56-24.53 21.29-25.58Q19.03-26.63 15.71-26.63L15.71-26.63Q12.47-26.63 10.31-25.75Q8.15-24.86 6.99-23.67Q5.84-22.47 5.67-21.23Q5.50-19.99 6.26-19.24L6.26-19.24Q6.68-18.82 6.36-18.29Q6.05-17.77 5.36-17.30Q4.66-16.84 3.72-16.57Q2.77-16.30 1.93-16.34Q1.09-16.38 0.50-16.88Q-0.08-17.39-0.08-18.48L-0.08-18.48Q-0.08-20.12 0.78-21.55Q1.64-22.97 3.11-24.19Q4.58-25.41 6.47-26.33Q8.36-27.26 10.44-27.93Q12.52-28.60 14.60-28.94Q16.67-29.27 18.52-29.27L18.52-29.27Q22.26-29.27 25.12-28.08Q27.97-26.88 29.95-24.93Q31.92-22.97 32.97-20.45Q34.02-17.93 34.17-15.27Q34.31-12.60 33.50-10.02Q32.68-7.43 30.91-5.31Q29.15-3.19 26.42-1.76Q23.69-0.34 19.95 0ZM5.54-2.35L5.54-2.35Q6.05-2.98 6.55-4.45Q7.06-5.92 7.50-7.81Q7.94-9.70 8.29-11.80Q8.65-13.90 8.88-15.73Q9.11-17.56 9.20-18.92Q9.28-20.29 9.20-20.75L9.20-20.75Q9.07-21.34 9.93-21.71Q10.79-22.09 11.93-21.99Q13.06-21.88 14.11-21.21Q15.16-20.54 15.50-19.03L15.50-19.03Q15.83-17.35 15.88-15.44Q15.92-13.52 15.54-11.47Q15.16-9.41 14.34-7.22Q13.52-5.04 12.18-2.77L12.18-2.77Q11.59-1.81 10.77-1.26Q9.95-0.71 9.09-0.53Q8.23-0.34 7.41-0.42Q6.59-0.50 6.05-0.78Q5.50-1.05 5.33-1.47Q5.17-1.89 5.54-2.35ZM38.85 0L38.85 0Q37.25 0 36.12-0.99Q34.99-1.97 34.61-3.40L34.61-3.40Q33.98-5.71 34.86-8.90L34.86-8.90Q35.57-11.51 37.00-13.84Q38.43-16.17 40.45-17.98L40.45-17.98Q42.34-19.74 44.16-20.50Q45.99-21.25 47.33-20.92L47.33-20.92Q48.05-20.71 48.59-20.22Q49.14-19.74 49.35-19.11L49.35-19.11Q49.85-17.81 49.39-15.83L49.39-15.83Q49.31-15.37 48.95-15.16Q48.59-14.95 48.17-15.04L48.17-15.04Q47.71-15.12 47.48-15.48Q47.25-15.83 47.33-16.25L47.33-16.25Q47.42-16.55 47.50-17.07Q47.59-17.60 47.25-17.60L47.25-17.60Q46.66-17.60 45.80-16.74Q44.94-15.88 44.04-14.55Q43.13-13.23 42.34-11.57Q41.54-9.91 41.08-8.36L41.08-8.36Q40.74-7.22 40.61-6.09Q40.49-4.96 40.64-4.20Q40.78-3.44 41.31-3.26Q41.83-3.07 42.80-3.91L42.80-3.91Q43.93-4.87 45.49-6.80Q47.04-8.74 48.68-12.14L48.68-12.14Q48.72-12.35 48.89-12.68L48.89-12.68Q48.97-12.89 49.06-13.04Q49.14-13.19 49.22-13.36L49.22-13.36L49.35-13.52Q50.19-14.66 51.43-14.93Q52.67-15.20 53.76-15.04Q54.85-14.87 55.52-14.45Q56.20-14.03 55.90-13.73L55.90-13.73Q55.61-13.44 55.29-12.58Q54.98-11.72 54.71-10.63Q54.43-9.53 54.26-8.34Q54.10-7.14 54.08-6.13Q54.05-5.12 54.20-4.47Q54.35-3.82 54.73-3.82L54.73-3.82Q55.06-3.82 55.42-4.05Q55.78-4.28 56.09-4.60Q56.41-4.91 56.68-5.27Q56.95-5.63 57.16-5.84L57.16-5.84Q57.88-6.68 58.51-7.50Q59.14-8.32 59.58-8.97Q60.02-9.62 60.29-10.04Q60.56-10.46 60.56-10.46L60.56-10.46Q60.77-10.84 61.19-10.94Q61.61-11.05 61.99-10.79L61.99-10.79Q62.37-10.58 62.48-10.16Q62.58-9.74 62.37-9.37L62.37-9.37Q62.33-9.32 62.06-8.90Q61.78-8.48 61.30-7.79Q60.82-7.10 60.17-6.24Q59.51-5.38 58.76-4.49L58.76-4.49Q54.85 0 51.79 0L51.79 0Q50.78 0 49.94-0.46Q49.10-0.92 48.64-1.72L48.64-1.72Q48.17-2.44 47.96-3.72Q47.75-5.00 47.80-6.51L47.80-6.51Q46.83-5.17 45.78-3.99Q44.73-2.81 43.60-1.93Q42.46-1.05 41.27-0.53Q40.07 0 38.85 0ZM63.80 0.04L63.80 0.04Q62.16 0.04 61.28-1.30L61.28-1.30Q60.77-2.02 60.52-3.40Q60.27-4.79 60.25-6.47Q60.23-8.15 60.42-10.02Q60.61-11.89 60.96-13.57Q61.32-15.25 61.82-16.61Q62.33-17.98 62.92-18.69L62.92-18.69Q64.13-20.12 65.50-20.54Q66.86-20.96 67.94-20.81Q69.01-20.66 69.55-20.16Q70.10-19.66 69.59-19.24L69.59-19.24Q69.38-19.07 68.98-17.83Q68.59-16.59 68.15-14.85Q67.70-13.10 67.31-11.11Q66.91-9.11 66.76-7.41Q66.61-5.71 66.78-4.60Q66.95-3.49 67.62-3.49L67.62-3.49Q68.75-3.49 70.06-4.81Q71.36-6.13 72.58-8.06Q73.79-10.00 74.76-12.20Q75.73-14.41 76.15-16.21L76.15-16.21Q76.36-17.14 76.44-17.89Q76.52-18.65 76.40-19.11Q76.27-19.57 75.89-19.72Q75.52-19.87 74.84-19.53L74.84-19.53Q74.30-19.28 73.96-19.93Q73.63-20.58 73.63-21.48Q73.63-22.39 74.07-23.16Q74.51-23.94 75.52-23.94L75.52-23.94Q76.61-23.94 77.24-23.42Q77.87-22.89 78.16-22.09Q78.46-21.29 78.52-20.39Q78.58-19.49 78.58-18.73L78.58-18.73Q78.58-17.51 78.29-16.09Q77.99-14.66 77.45-13.15Q76.90-11.63 76.13-10.08Q75.35-8.53 74.38-7.14L74.38-7.14Q71.99-3.65 69.36-1.81Q66.74 0.04 63.80 0.04ZM82.91 0L82.91 0Q81.90 0 81.06-0.46Q80.22-0.92 79.76-1.72L79.76-1.72Q79.30-2.48 79.11-3.78Q78.92-5.08 78.94-6.68Q78.96-8.27 79.17-10.04Q79.38-11.80 79.65-13.40Q79.93-14.99 80.28-16.34Q80.64-17.68 80.98-18.48L80.98-18.48Q81.65-20.03 82.95-20.54Q84.25-21.04 85.49-20.92Q86.73-20.79 87.53-20.33Q88.33-19.87 87.99-19.53L87.99-19.53Q87.70-19.24 87.30-17.96Q86.90-16.67 86.54-14.93Q86.18-13.19 85.89-11.24Q85.60-9.28 85.45-7.62Q85.30-5.96 85.39-4.89Q85.47-3.82 85.85-3.82L85.85-3.82Q86.18-3.82 86.54-4.05Q86.90-4.28 87.21-4.60Q87.53-4.91 87.80-5.27Q88.07-5.63 88.28-5.84L88.28-5.84Q89.00-6.68 89.63-7.50Q90.26-8.32 90.70-8.97Q91.14-9.62 91.41-10.04Q91.69-10.46 91.69-10.46L91.69-10.46Q91.90-10.84 92.32-10.94Q92.74-11.05 93.11-10.79L93.11-10.79Q93.49-10.58 93.60-10.16Q93.70-9.74 93.49-9.37L93.49-9.37Q93.45-9.32 93.18-8.90Q92.90-8.48 92.42-7.79Q91.94-7.10 91.29-6.24Q90.64-5.38 89.88-4.49L89.88-4.49Q85.97 0 82.91 0ZM89.25-26.50L89.25-26.50Q89.04-25.87 88.62-25.33Q88.20-24.78 87.61-24.34Q87.02-23.90 86.33-23.63Q85.64-23.35 84.92-23.31L84.92-23.31Q84.25-23.27 83.73-23.50Q83.20-23.73 82.89-24.13Q82.57-24.53 82.51-25.05Q82.45-25.58 82.66-26.21L82.66-26.21Q82.82-26.84 83.27-27.38Q83.71-27.93 84.29-28.35Q84.88-28.77 85.55-29.02Q86.23-29.27 86.90-29.32L86.90-29.32Q88.28-29.44 88.98-28.58Q89.67-27.72 89.25-26.50ZM108.61 0L108.61 0Q107.56 0 106.87-0.61Q106.18-1.22 105.76-2.29Q105.34-3.36 105.17-4.81Q105.00-6.26 105.00-7.98L105.00-7.98Q104.03-6.43 102.88-4.98Q101.72-3.53 100.44-2.44Q99.16-1.34 97.82-0.67Q96.47 0 95.09 0L95.09 0Q93.49 0 92.36-0.99Q91.22-1.97 90.85-3.40L90.85-3.40Q90.22-5.71 91.10-8.90L91.10-8.90Q91.81-11.51 93.24-13.84Q94.67-16.17 96.68-17.98L96.68-17.98Q98.57-19.74 100.40-20.50Q102.23-21.25 103.57-20.92L103.57-20.92Q104.29-20.71 104.83-20.22Q105.38-19.74 105.59-19.11L105.59-19.11Q106.09-17.81 105.63-15.83L105.63-15.83Q105.55-15.37 105.19-15.16Q104.83-14.95 104.41-15.04L104.41-15.04Q103.95-15.12 103.72-15.48Q103.49-15.83 103.57-16.25L103.57-16.25Q103.66-16.55 103.74-17.07Q103.82-17.60 103.49-17.60L103.49-17.60Q102.90-17.60 102.04-16.74Q101.18-15.88 100.28-14.55Q99.37-13.23 98.57-11.57Q97.78-9.91 97.31-8.36L97.31-8.36Q96.98-7.22 96.85-6.09Q96.73-4.96 96.87-4.20Q97.02-3.44 97.55-3.26Q98.07-3.07 99.04-3.91L99.04-3.91Q100.25-4.96 101.98-7.14Q103.70-9.32 105.42-13.23L105.42-13.23L105.42-13.27Q105.76-15.79 106.26-18.27Q106.76-20.75 107.31-22.89Q107.86-25.03 108.38-26.63Q108.91-28.22 109.28-28.94L109.28-28.94Q109.79-29.95 110.59-30.49Q111.38-31.04 112.22-31.23Q113.06-31.42 113.90-31.33Q114.74-31.25 115.35-31.02Q115.96-30.79 116.24-30.49Q116.51-30.20 116.30-29.99L116.30-29.99Q116.09-29.78 115.69-28.52Q115.29-27.26 114.83-25.39Q114.37-23.52 113.86-21.19Q113.36-18.86 112.90-16.46Q112.43-14.07 112.06-11.78Q111.68-9.49 111.47-7.73Q111.26-5.96 111.26-4.89Q111.26-3.82 111.55-3.82L111.55-3.82Q111.89-3.82 112.25-4.05Q112.60-4.28 112.92-4.60Q113.23-4.91 113.51-5.27Q113.78-5.63 113.99-5.84L113.99-5.84Q114.70-6.68 115.33-7.50Q115.96-8.32 116.40-8.97Q116.84-9.62 117.12-10.04Q117.39-10.46 117.39-10.46L117.39-10.46Q117.60-10.84 118.02-10.94Q118.44-11.05 118.82-10.79L118.82-10.79Q119.20-10.58 119.30-10.16Q119.41-9.74 119.20-9.37L119.20-9.37Q119.15-9.32 118.88-8.90Q118.61-8.48 118.13-7.79Q117.64-7.10 116.99-6.24Q116.34-5.38 115.58-4.49L115.58-4.49Q111.68 0 108.61 0Z" transform="translate(50.86000366210938, 215)" /></g>
</g>
</svg>`

Problema não consigo centrar o segundo svg dentro do primeiro.
Alguém consegue ajudar ?

Comment: Cara não entendi direito o que vc quer... Seria colocar a logo no meio do rect? Tipo centralizar a logo no meio do quadrado? Reparei que os dois são pretos, se um ficar encima do outro vc só vai ver um box preto...

Comment: O objectivo seria centro o logo no no elemento rect

Comment: Peço desculpa o código não está muito percetível mas é complicado por aqui xml.... do retângulo só estão visíveis as bordas, o fundo é branco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adriano não sou especialista em SVG, mas fiz uns ajustes que acho que pode te ajudar. A primeira coisa foi refazer esse `rect` preto de fora, pois a sintax dele estava bem estranho na verdade... Depois colocai tanto a logo quando o `rect` dentro do mesmo `<svg>` pra facilitar.

Depois ajustei com algum css para ficar um no meio do outro. Veja se é isso que vc queria.

```css
svg {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
   path {
    fill: black;
   }

   #logo {
    transform: scale(0.5) translate(-10%, -100%);
   }
  </style>
  <rect width="100" height="100" fill="#C4C4C4" />
  <!-- <rect width="50" height="50" transform="translate(25 25)" fill="#DE1111"/> -->
  <g id="logo" width="50" height="50">
   <g id="firstG">
    <path id="g01" d="M66.8,257.7c-1.1,0.9-2.2,2.4-3.9,2c-1.4-0.3-2.1-1.4-2.5-2.7c-0.4-1.1-0.7-2.3,0.2-3.3c0.8-0.9,2.2-1.2,3.4-1.3   c1.4-0.1,2.5,0,2.8,1.6c0.1,0.6,0.1,1.1,0.6,1.5c0.5,0.5,1.3,0.8,1.9,1.2c2.8,2.1,5.8,3.5,9.2,4.5c-0.7-1.6-1.3-3.1-2-4.7   c-0.1-0.3-0.3-1.1-0.5-1.2c-0.1-0.1-0.6,0.1-0.8,0c-0.5,0-0.9-0.3-1.3-0.6c-0.6-0.6-1.3-1.8-1.5-2.6c-0.5-1.6,1.2-1.2,2.1-1   c0.2-2.1,2.2-6.3,5-4.5c1.2,0.8,1.4,2.4,1.1,3.7c-0.1,0.7-0.4,1.4-0.8,2c-0.4,0.6-1.1,1-1.5,1.5c-0.8,1.1,0.9,2.9,1.4,3.9   c0.4,0.7,0.9,1.5,1,2.2c0.1,0.3,0.1,0.6,0.1,1c0.1,0.7,0,0.8,0.7,0.9c3.7,0.5,7.3,1.1,11,1.5c4,0.5,8.1,1.2,12.2,0.8   c-1.1-1.8-2.1-3.6-3.3-5.3c-0.5-0.7-0.7-0.6-1.5-0.4c-0.7,0.1-1.2-0.1-1.8-0.5c-0.5-0.4-1.1-1-1.3-1.7c-0.2-0.8,0.3-1.9,0.6-2.8   c0.6-1.6,1.4-3,3.2-3.3c1.4-0.2,3.3,0.2,4.2,1.4c1,1.5,0.2,3.2-0.7,4.5c-0.3,0.4-0.6,0.8-0.9,1.1c-0.1,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.4,0.5   c-0.4,0.7-0.2,0.1-0.1,0.6c0.3,0.8,1.3,1.8,1.8,2.5c0.5,0.7,1.2,1.4,1.5,2.2c0.3,0.7,0.4,1.1,1.2,1.3c1.1,0.2,2.4,0,3.4,0   c1.3,0,2.5,0,3.8-0.1c2.4,0,4.8-0.1,7.1-0.1c-0.9-1.4-1.8-3.3-3.1-4.5c-1-1-2.7-0.5-4-0.9c-1.4-0.4-2.5-1.6-2.4-3.1   c0.2-1.8,1.8-2.4,3.4-2.6c1.6-0.3,3.4-0.4,4.3,1.2c0.4,0.7,0.5,1.3,0.3,2c-0.2,0.6-1.2,1.8-1,2.4c0.2,0.7,1.4,1.5,1.9,2   c0.7,0.7,1.3,1.4,2.1,2.1c0.5,0.4,1.2,1.1,1.9,1.3c1,0.3,2.3,0.1,3.3,0.1c2.1,0,4.2-0.1,6.2-0.5c0.8-0.1,1.7-0.4,2.5-0.6   c0.6-0.1,0.6-0.1,0.8,0.4c0.1,0.4,0.3,0.8,0.2,1.2c-0.1,0.7-0.7,0.8-1.3,0.9c-1.1,0.1-2.2,0.1-3.3,0.1c-2.1,0.1-4.3,0.2-6.4,0.3   c-2.2,0.1-4.6,0-6.7,0.3c-0.9,0.1-0.9,0.5-1.3,1.3c-0.4,0.8-0.9,1.5-1.5,2.1c-0.5,0.5-1.3,1.1-1.6,1.7c-0.4,0.8-0.2,2.2-0.2,3.1   c-0.1,1.6-0.7,2.8-2.1,3.8c-1.2,0.9-2.6,0.7-3.9,0.1c-1.2-0.6-2.6-2.5-1.9-3.9c0.4-0.9,1.4-1.6,2.3-2.1c0.9-0.5,1.8-0.6,2.7-1   c0.9-0.4,1.7-1.4,2.4-2.1c0.9-0.9,1.6-1.8,2.3-2.8c-4.3-0.1-8.6-0.2-12.9-0.4c-2.1-0.1-4.2-0.1-6.4-0.2c-0.5,0-1.1-0.1-1.5,0   c-0.6,0.1-0.7,0.3-1.1,0.8c-0.6,0.8-1.2,1.6-1.8,2.3c-1,1.2-2.4,1.9-2.7,3.6c-0.1,0.6,0,1.1-0.4,1.7c-0.4,0.6-1,1-1.7,1.3   c-1.5,0.7-3,0.3-4.2-0.7c-1-0.8-1.6-1.9-0.7-3c1.1-1.4,3.3-2.7,5.1-2.5c1.1,0.1,1.5-0.6,2.2-1.4c0.8-0.8,1.6-1.7,2.4-2.5   c-3.4-0.6-7-0.5-10.4-1.2c-0.7-0.1-1.4-0.5-2.2-0.4c-0.8,0.1-1.6,0.7-2.3,1.1c-1.3,0.8-2.7,1.4-2.7,3.1c-0.1,2.6-2.1,4.1-4.6,3.4   c-1.2-0.3-2.5-0.4-2.9-1.7c-0.3-1,0-2.3,0.7-3.1c1-1.2,2.8-1.4,4.3-1.5c0.9-0.1,1.7,0.1,2.5-0.3c0.8-0.4,1.5-1.1,2.2-1.7   C74.3,262.9,70.6,260.2,66.8,257.7z M101,252.5c-2.9,0-3,4.4,0.1,3.8c1-0.2,2-1,2.1-2C103.4,253,102.1,252.5,101,252.5z M61.4,256   c0,0.9,0.5,2.5,1.6,2.1c0.9-0.3,1.7-1.4,1.6-2.3c0-1.1-1-1.5-1.9-1.5C61.8,254.4,61.4,255.1,61.4,256z M116.5,257.4   c0.8,0,2.1-0.2,1.7-1.3c-0.3-1-1.5-1.3-2.5-1.3c-0.9,0-2.1,0.4-1.6,1.6C114.5,257.4,115.6,257.3,116.5,257.4z M70.4,268.3   c0.8,0.6,1.8,1.6,2.9,1.7c1.1,0.1,1.6-0.6,1.3-1.6C74.1,266.8,70.9,266.6,70.4,268.3z M75.5,252.8c0.8,0.9,1.1,0.3,1.7-0.4   c0.7-0.9,1.4-1.7,0.8-2.8c-0.3-0.5-0.5-0.9-1-0.6c-0.4,0.2-0.6,0.6-0.7,0.9C75.9,250.7,75.8,251.8,75.5,252.8z M109.4,275.2   c0.6,0.6,1.3,1.4,2.2,1.5c0.8,0.1,1.9-0.4,2-1.3C113.8,273.3,110.2,274.5,109.4,275.2z M88.2,273.9c0.5-0.2,0.4-0.3,0.4-0.8   c0-0.3,0-0.5-0.2-0.8c-0.6-0.7-1.6-0.3-2.1,0.2C86.9,273,87.6,273.4,88.2,273.9z"
    />
   </g>
   <g id="secondG">
    <g id="thirdG">
     <path d="M0.88-13.57L0.88-13.57L2.98-13.69Q3.99-16.59 5.82-19.40Q7.64-22.22 9.95-24.44Q12.26-26.67 14.85-28.04Q17.43-29.40 19.99-29.40L19.99-29.40Q20.96-29.40 21.99-28.94Q23.02-28.48 23.73-27.55Q24.44-26.63 24.68-25.22Q24.91-23.81 24.23-21.92L24.23-21.92Q24.02-21.34 23.48-21.08Q22.93-20.83 22.24-20.83Q21.55-20.83 20.87-21.04Q20.20-21.25 19.74-21.57Q19.28-21.88 19.15-22.24Q19.03-22.60 19.49-22.89L19.49-22.89Q20.12-23.31 20.60-24.05Q21.08-24.78 21.25-25.49Q21.42-26.21 21.11-26.73Q20.79-27.26 19.78-27.26L19.78-27.26Q18.98-27.26 17.75-26.12Q16.51-24.99 15.12-23.14Q13.73-21.29 12.35-18.94Q10.96-16.59 9.95-14.20L9.95-14.20L19.28-14.83Q19.78-14.83 20.08-14.51Q20.37-14.20 20.39-13.82Q20.41-13.44 20.20-13.10Q19.99-12.77 19.49-12.73L19.49-12.73L8.90-11.42Q8.27-9.53 8.09-7.85Q7.90-6.17 8.27-4.91Q8.65-3.65 9.68-2.90Q10.71-2.14 12.60-2.14L12.60-2.14Q13.73-2.14 15.16-2.52Q16.59-2.90 18.33-3.86Q20.08-4.83 22.18-6.49Q24.28-8.15 26.75-10.67L26.75-10.67Q27.09-11.00 27.49-11.00Q27.89-11.00 28.22-10.71L28.22-10.71Q28.56-10.37 28.56-9.95Q28.56-9.53 28.27-9.20L28.27-9.20Q26.42-7.35 24.74-5.78Q23.06-4.20 21.27-3.00Q19.49-1.81 17.51-1.05Q15.54-0.29 13.15-0.04L13.15-0.04Q9.58 0.21 7.27-0.57Q4.96-1.34 3.65-2.81Q2.35-4.28 2.02-6.30Q1.68-8.32 2.10-10.63L2.10-10.63L1.05-10.50Q0.59-10.54 0.32-11.03Q0.04-11.51 0-12.03Q-0.04-12.56 0.17-13.02Q0.38-13.48 0.88-13.57ZM30.07 0.04L30.07 0.04Q28.43 0.04 27.55-1.30L27.55-1.30Q27.05-2.02 26.80-3.40Q26.54-4.79 26.52-6.47Q26.50-8.15 26.69-10.02Q26.88-11.89 27.24-13.57Q27.59-15.25 28.10-16.61Q28.60-17.98 29.19-18.69L29.19-18.69Q30.41-20.12 31.77-20.54Q33.14-20.96 34.21-20.81Q35.28-20.66 35.83-20.16Q36.37-19.66 35.87-19.24L35.87-19.24Q35.66-19.07 35.26-17.83Q34.86-16.59 34.42-14.85Q33.98-13.10 33.58-11.11Q33.18-9.11 33.03-7.41Q32.89-5.71 33.05-4.60Q33.22-3.49 33.89-3.49L33.89-3.49Q35.03-3.49 36.33-4.81Q37.63-6.13 38.85-8.06Q40.07-10.00 41.03-12.20Q42-14.41 42.42-16.21L42.42-16.21Q42.63-17.14 42.71-17.89Q42.80-18.65 42.67-19.11Q42.55-19.57 42.17-19.72Q41.79-19.87 41.12-19.53L41.12-19.53Q40.57-19.28 40.24-19.93Q39.90-20.58 39.90-21.48Q39.90-22.39 40.34-23.16Q40.78-23.94 41.79-23.94L41.79-23.94Q42.88-23.94 43.51-23.42Q44.14-22.89 44.44-22.09Q44.73-21.29 44.79-20.39Q44.86-19.49 44.86-18.73L44.86-18.73Q44.86-17.51 44.56-16.09Q44.27-14.66 43.72-13.15Q43.18-11.63 42.40-10.08Q41.62-8.53 40.66-7.14L40.66-7.14Q38.26-3.65 35.64-1.81Q33.01 0.04 30.07 0.04ZM48.85 0L48.85 0Q47.25 0 46.12-0.99Q44.98-1.97 44.60-3.40L44.60-3.40Q43.97-5.71 44.86-8.90L44.86-8.90Q45.57-11.51 47.00-13.84Q48.43-16.17 50.44-17.98L50.44-17.98Q52.33-19.74 54.16-20.50Q55.99-21.25 57.33-20.92L57.33-20.92Q58.04-20.71 58.59-20.22Q59.14-19.74 59.35-19.11L59.35-19.11Q59.85-17.81 59.39-15.83L59.39-15.83Q59.30-15.37 58.95-15.16Q58.59-14.95 58.17-15.04L58.17-15.04Q57.71-15.12 57.48-15.48Q57.25-15.83 57.33-16.25L57.33-16.25Q57.41-16.55 57.50-17.07Q57.58-17.60 57.25-17.60L57.25-17.60Q56.66-17.60 55.80-16.74Q54.94-15.88 54.03-14.55Q53.13-13.23 52.33-11.57Q51.53-9.91 51.07-8.36L51.07-8.36Q50.74-7.22 50.61-6.09Q50.48-4.96 50.63-4.20Q50.78-3.44 51.30-3.26Q51.83-3.07 52.79-3.91L52.79-3.91Q53.93-4.87 55.48-6.80Q57.04-8.74 58.67-12.14L58.67-12.14Q58.72-12.35 58.88-12.68L58.88-12.68Q58.97-12.89 59.05-13.04Q59.14-13.19 59.22-13.36L59.22-13.36L59.35-13.52Q60.19-14.66 61.42-14.93Q62.66-15.20 63.76-15.04Q64.85-14.87 65.52-14.45Q66.19-14.03 65.90-13.73L65.90-13.73Q65.60-13.44 65.29-12.58Q64.97-11.72 64.70-10.63Q64.43-9.53 64.26-8.34Q64.09-7.14 64.07-6.13Q64.05-5.12 64.20-4.47Q64.34-3.82 64.72-3.82L64.72-3.82Q65.06-3.82 65.41-4.05Q65.77-4.28 66.09-4.60Q66.40-4.91 66.67-5.27Q66.95-5.63 67.16-5.84L67.16-5.84Q67.87-6.68 68.50-7.50Q69.13-8.32 69.57-8.97Q70.01-9.62 70.29-10.04Q70.56-10.46 70.56-10.46L70.56-10.46Q70.77-10.84 71.19-10.94Q71.61-11.05 71.99-10.79L71.99-10.79Q72.37-10.58 72.47-10.16Q72.58-9.74 72.37-9.37L72.37-9.37Q72.32-9.32 72.05-8.90Q71.78-8.48 71.30-7.79Q70.81-7.10 70.16-6.24Q69.51-5.38 68.75-4.49L68.75-4.49Q64.85 0 61.78 0L61.78 0Q60.77 0 59.93-0.46Q59.09-0.92 58.63-1.72L58.63-1.72Q58.17-2.44 57.96-3.72Q57.75-5.00 57.79-6.51L57.79-6.51Q56.83-5.17 55.78-3.99Q54.73-2.81 53.59-1.93Q52.46-1.05 51.26-0.53Q50.06 0 48.85 0Z"
         transform="translate(56.70000457763672, 145)" />
    </g>
    <path id="g18" d="M117.8,166.6c0,0.4-0.2,0.9-0.6,1.5c-0.4,0.6-0.9,1.2-1.5,1.9c-0.6,0.7-1.2,1.3-1.9,1.9c-0.7,0.6-1.2,1.1-1.7,1.5   c0.4,0.6,0.7,1.1,0.9,1.5c0.2,0.4,0.3,0.6,0.4,0.6c0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.5c0,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.3,0.5c-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.1   c-0.2,0-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.3c0,0-0.1-0.2-0.4-0.6c-0.2-0.3-0.5-0.8-0.8-1.3c0,0-0.1,0-0.1,0c0,0,0,0-0.1,0c-1,0.7-1.9,1.2-2.8,1.6   c-0.9,0.4-1.8,0.6-2.6,0.6h-0.1c-1.1,0-1.9-0.4-2.4-1.1c-0.5-0.6-0.6-1.4-0.4-2.4c0.2-0.8,0.5-1.6,1.1-2.6c0.4-0.8,0.9-1.6,1.5-2.4   c0.6-0.8,1.2-1.6,1.9-2.5c-0.6-2.2-0.7-4-0.3-5.4c0.2-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.6-1.4c0.3-0.4,0.6-0.8,0.9-1.1c0.4-0.4,0.9-0.7,1.4-0.9   c0.6-0.2,1.1-0.4,1.7-0.4c0.6,0,1.2,0,1.7,0.2c0.6,0.2,1,0.5,1.4,1c0.5,0.5,0.7,1.2,0.7,1.9c0,0.8-0.3,1.6-0.8,2.4   c-0.4,0.6-0.9,1.3-1.4,2c-0.5,0.7-1.1,1.4-1.6,2.1c-0.7,0.8-1.3,1.7-1.9,2.5c0.1,0.3,0.3,0.7,0.5,1.1c0.2,0.4,0.4,0.9,0.6,1.2   s0.4,0.8,0.6,1.2c0.4-0.4,0.8-0.8,1.2-1.3s0.8-1,1.1-1.5c0.3-0.5,0.6-1,0.8-1.6c0.2-0.5,0.3-1.1,0.3-1.6c0-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.5-0.4   c0.3-0.1,0.7-0.1,1,0c0.4,0.1,0.7,0.2,1,0.3C117.6,166.2,117.8,166.4,117.8,166.6z M107.7,171.5c-0.6,1.1-1,1.9-1,2.4   s0.1,0.8,0.4,0.8c0.3,0,0.8-0.1,1.3-0.4s1.2-0.7,1.9-1.3c-0.3-0.5-0.6-1-0.9-1.5c-0.3-0.5-0.5-1.1-0.7-1.6   c-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.6-0.5,0.8C108,171,107.8,171.3,107.7,171.5z M108.1,160.7c-0.3,1-0.3,2.2,0.1,3.6c0.5-0.6,1-1.2,1.4-1.8   c0.4-0.6,0.8-1.1,1.2-1.7c0.4-0.7,0.7-1.2,0.7-1.6c0.1-0.4,0-0.7-0.2-0.8c-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.2-0.7-0.2c-0.3,0-0.7,0.2-1,0.4   c-0.3,0.2-0.6,0.5-0.9,0.9C108.4,159.9,108.2,160.3,108.1,160.7z"
    />
    <g id="fourdG">
     <path d="M19.95 0L19.95 0Q18.77 0.08 17.77-0.23Q16.76-0.55 16.00-1.20Q15.25-1.85 14.83-2.77Q14.41-3.70 14.41-4.83L14.41-4.83Q14.41-5.33 14.89-5.61Q15.37-5.88 15.96-5.90Q16.55-5.92 17.03-5.69Q17.51-5.46 17.51-4.96L17.51-4.96Q17.51-4.07 17.72-3.51Q17.93-2.94 18.25-2.63Q18.56-2.31 18.94-2.21Q19.32-2.10 19.70-2.10L19.70-2.10Q21.08-2.10 22.39-3.15Q23.69-4.20 24.72-5.92Q25.75-7.64 26.42-9.85Q27.09-12.05 27.20-14.36Q27.30-16.67 26.78-18.88Q26.25-21.08 24.91-22.81Q23.56-24.53 21.29-25.58Q19.03-26.63 15.71-26.63L15.71-26.63Q12.47-26.63 10.31-25.75Q8.15-24.86 6.99-23.67Q5.84-22.47 5.67-21.23Q5.50-19.99 6.26-19.24L6.26-19.24Q6.68-18.82 6.36-18.29Q6.05-17.77 5.36-17.30Q4.66-16.84 3.72-16.57Q2.77-16.30 1.93-16.34Q1.09-16.38 0.50-16.88Q-0.08-17.39-0.08-18.48L-0.08-18.48Q-0.08-20.12 0.78-21.55Q1.64-22.97 3.11-24.19Q4.58-25.41 6.47-26.33Q8.36-27.26 10.44-27.93Q12.52-28.60 14.60-28.94Q16.67-29.27 18.52-29.27L18.52-29.27Q22.26-29.27 25.12-28.08Q27.97-26.88 29.95-24.93Q31.92-22.97 32.97-20.45Q34.02-17.93 34.17-15.27Q34.31-12.60 33.50-10.02Q32.68-7.43 30.91-5.31Q29.15-3.19 26.42-1.76Q23.69-0.34 19.95 0ZM5.54-2.35L5.54-2.35Q6.05-2.98 6.55-4.45Q7.06-5.92 7.50-7.81Q7.94-9.70 8.29-11.80Q8.65-13.90 8.88-15.73Q9.11-17.56 9.20-18.92Q9.28-20.29 9.20-20.75L9.20-20.75Q9.07-21.34 9.93-21.71Q10.79-22.09 11.93-21.99Q13.06-21.88 14.11-21.21Q15.16-20.54 15.50-19.03L15.50-19.03Q15.83-17.35 15.88-15.44Q15.92-13.52 15.54-11.47Q15.16-9.41 14.34-7.22Q13.52-5.04 12.18-2.77L12.18-2.77Q11.59-1.81 10.77-1.26Q9.95-0.71 9.09-0.53Q8.23-0.34 7.41-0.42Q6.59-0.50 6.05-0.78Q5.50-1.05 5.33-1.47Q5.17-1.89 5.54-2.35ZM38.85 0L38.85 0Q37.25 0 36.12-0.99Q34.99-1.97 34.61-3.40L34.61-3.40Q33.98-5.71 34.86-8.90L34.86-8.90Q35.57-11.51 37.00-13.84Q38.43-16.17 40.45-17.98L40.45-17.98Q42.34-19.74 44.16-20.50Q45.99-21.25 47.33-20.92L47.33-20.92Q48.05-20.71 48.59-20.22Q49.14-19.74 49.35-19.11L49.35-19.11Q49.85-17.81 49.39-15.83L49.39-15.83Q49.31-15.37 48.95-15.16Q48.59-14.95 48.17-15.04L48.17-15.04Q47.71-15.12 47.48-15.48Q47.25-15.83 47.33-16.25L47.33-16.25Q47.42-16.55 47.50-17.07Q47.59-17.60 47.25-17.60L47.25-17.60Q46.66-17.60 45.80-16.74Q44.94-15.88 44.04-14.55Q43.13-13.23 42.34-11.57Q41.54-9.91 41.08-8.36L41.08-8.36Q40.74-7.22 40.61-6.09Q40.49-4.96 40.64-4.20Q40.78-3.44 41.31-3.26Q41.83-3.07 42.80-3.91L42.80-3.91Q43.93-4.87 45.49-6.80Q47.04-8.74 48.68-12.14L48.68-12.14Q48.72-12.35 48.89-12.68L48.89-12.68Q48.97-12.89 49.06-13.04Q49.14-13.19 49.22-13.36L49.22-13.36L49.35-13.52Q50.19-14.66 51.43-14.93Q52.67-15.20 53.76-15.04Q54.85-14.87 55.52-14.45Q56.20-14.03 55.90-13.73L55.90-13.73Q55.61-13.44 55.29-12.58Q54.98-11.72 54.71-10.63Q54.43-9.53 54.26-8.34Q54.10-7.14 54.08-6.13Q54.05-5.12 54.20-4.47Q54.35-3.82 54.73-3.82L54.73-3.82Q55.06-3.82 55.42-4.05Q55.78-4.28 56.09-4.60Q56.41-4.91 56.68-5.27Q56.95-5.63 57.16-5.84L57.16-5.84Q57.88-6.68 58.51-7.50Q59.14-8.32 59.58-8.97Q60.02-9.62 60.29-10.04Q60.56-10.46 60.56-10.46L60.56-10.46Q60.77-10.84 61.19-10.94Q61.61-11.05 61.99-10.79L61.99-10.79Q62.37-10.58 62.48-10.16Q62.58-9.74 62.37-9.37L62.37-9.37Q62.33-9.32 62.06-8.90Q61.78-8.48 61.30-7.79Q60.82-7.10 60.17-6.24Q59.51-5.38 58.76-4.49L58.76-4.49Q54.85 0 51.79 0L51.79 0Q50.78 0 49.94-0.46Q49.10-0.92 48.64-1.72L48.64-1.72Q48.17-2.44 47.96-3.72Q47.75-5.00 47.80-6.51L47.80-6.51Q46.83-5.17 45.78-3.99Q44.73-2.81 43.60-1.93Q42.46-1.05 41.27-0.53Q40.07 0 38.85 0ZM63.80 0.04L63.80 0.04Q62.16 0.04 61.28-1.30L61.28-1.30Q60.77-2.02 60.52-3.40Q60.27-4.79 60.25-6.47Q60.23-8.15 60.42-10.02Q60.61-11.89 60.96-13.57Q61.32-15.25 61.82-16.61Q62.33-17.98 62.92-18.69L62.92-18.69Q64.13-20.12 65.50-20.54Q66.86-20.96 67.94-20.81Q69.01-20.66 69.55-20.16Q70.10-19.66 69.59-19.24L69.59-19.24Q69.38-19.07 68.98-17.83Q68.59-16.59 68.15-14.85Q67.70-13.10 67.31-11.11Q66.91-9.11 66.76-7.41Q66.61-5.71 66.78-4.60Q66.95-3.49 67.62-3.49L67.62-3.49Q68.75-3.49 70.06-4.81Q71.36-6.13 72.58-8.06Q73.79-10.00 74.76-12.20Q75.73-14.41 76.15-16.21L76.15-16.21Q76.36-17.14 76.44-17.89Q76.52-18.65 76.40-19.11Q76.27-19.57 75.89-19.72Q75.52-19.87 74.84-19.53L74.84-19.53Q74.30-19.28 73.96-19.93Q73.63-20.58 73.63-21.48Q73.63-22.39 74.07-23.16Q74.51-23.94 75.52-23.94L75.52-23.94Q76.61-23.94 77.24-23.42Q77.87-22.89 78.16-22.09Q78.46-21.29 78.52-20.39Q78.58-19.49 78.58-18.73L78.58-18.73Q78.58-17.51 78.29-16.09Q77.99-14.66 77.45-13.15Q76.90-11.63 76.13-10.08Q75.35-8.53 74.38-7.14L74.38-7.14Q71.99-3.65 69.36-1.81Q66.74 0.04 63.80 0.04ZM82.91 0L82.91 0Q81.90 0 81.06-0.46Q80.22-0.92 79.76-1.72L79.76-1.72Q79.30-2.48 79.11-3.78Q78.92-5.08 78.94-6.68Q78.96-8.27 79.17-10.04Q79.38-11.80 79.65-13.40Q79.93-14.99 80.28-16.34Q80.64-17.68 80.98-18.48L80.98-18.48Q81.65-20.03 82.95-20.54Q84.25-21.04 85.49-20.92Q86.73-20.79 87.53-20.33Q88.33-19.87 87.99-19.53L87.99-19.53Q87.70-19.24 87.30-17.96Q86.90-16.67 86.54-14.93Q86.18-13.19 85.89-11.24Q85.60-9.28 85.45-7.62Q85.30-5.96 85.39-4.89Q85.47-3.82 85.85-3.82L85.85-3.82Q86.18-3.82 86.54-4.05Q86.90-4.28 87.21-4.60Q87.53-4.91 87.80-5.27Q88.07-5.63 88.28-5.84L88.28-5.84Q89.00-6.68 89.63-7.50Q90.26-8.32 90.70-8.97Q91.14-9.62 91.41-10.04Q91.69-10.46 91.69-10.46L91.69-10.46Q91.90-10.84 92.32-10.94Q92.74-11.05 93.11-10.79L93.11-10.79Q93.49-10.58 93.60-10.16Q93.70-9.74 93.49-9.37L93.49-9.37Q93.45-9.32 93.18-8.90Q92.90-8.48 92.42-7.79Q91.94-7.10 91.29-6.24Q90.64-5.38 89.88-4.49L89.88-4.49Q85.97 0 82.91 0ZM89.25-26.50L89.25-26.50Q89.04-25.87 88.62-25.33Q88.20-24.78 87.61-24.34Q87.02-23.90 86.33-23.63Q85.64-23.35 84.92-23.31L84.92-23.31Q84.25-23.27 83.73-23.50Q83.20-23.73 82.89-24.13Q82.57-24.53 82.51-25.05Q82.45-25.58 82.66-26.21L82.66-26.21Q82.82-26.84 83.27-27.38Q83.71-27.93 84.29-28.35Q84.88-28.77 85.55-29.02Q86.23-29.27 86.90-29.32L86.90-29.32Q88.28-29.44 88.98-28.58Q89.67-27.72 89.25-26.50ZM108.61 0L108.61 0Q107.56 0 106.87-0.61Q106.18-1.22 105.76-2.29Q105.34-3.36 105.17-4.81Q105.00-6.26 105.00-7.98L105.00-7.98Q104.03-6.43 102.88-4.98Q101.72-3.53 100.44-2.44Q99.16-1.34 97.82-0.67Q96.47 0 95.09 0L95.09 0Q93.49 0 92.36-0.99Q91.22-1.97 90.85-3.40L90.85-3.40Q90.22-5.71 91.10-8.90L91.10-8.90Q91.81-11.51 93.24-13.84Q94.67-16.17 96.68-17.98L96.68-17.98Q98.57-19.74 100.40-20.50Q102.23-21.25 103.57-20.92L103.57-20.92Q104.29-20.71 104.83-20.22Q105.38-19.74 105.59-19.11L105.59-19.11Q106.09-17.81 105.63-15.83L105.63-15.83Q105.55-15.37 105.19-15.16Q104.83-14.95 104.41-15.04L104.41-15.04Q103.95-15.12 103.72-15.48Q103.49-15.83 103.57-16.25L103.57-16.25Q103.66-16.55 103.74-17.07Q103.82-17.60 103.49-17.60L103.49-17.60Q102.90-17.60 102.04-16.74Q101.18-15.88 100.28-14.55Q99.37-13.23 98.57-11.57Q97.78-9.91 97.31-8.36L97.31-8.36Q96.98-7.22 96.85-6.09Q96.73-4.96 96.87-4.20Q97.02-3.44 97.55-3.26Q98.07-3.07 99.04-3.91L99.04-3.91Q100.25-4.96 101.98-7.14Q103.70-9.32 105.42-13.23L105.42-13.23L105.42-13.27Q105.76-15.79 106.26-18.27Q106.76-20.75 107.31-22.89Q107.86-25.03 108.38-26.63Q108.91-28.22 109.28-28.94L109.28-28.94Q109.79-29.95 110.59-30.49Q111.38-31.04 112.22-31.23Q113.06-31.42 113.90-31.33Q114.74-31.25 115.35-31.02Q115.96-30.79 116.24-30.49Q116.51-30.20 116.30-29.99L116.30-29.99Q116.09-29.78 115.69-28.52Q115.29-27.26 114.83-25.39Q114.37-23.52 113.86-21.19Q113.36-18.86 112.90-16.46Q112.43-14.07 112.06-11.78Q111.68-9.49 111.47-7.73Q111.26-5.96 111.26-4.89Q111.26-3.82 111.55-3.82L111.55-3.82Q111.89-3.82 112.25-4.05Q112.60-4.28 112.92-4.60Q113.23-4.91 113.51-5.27Q113.78-5.63 113.99-5.84L113.99-5.84Q114.70-6.68 115.33-7.50Q115.96-8.32 116.40-8.97Q116.84-9.62 117.12-10.04Q117.39-10.46 117.39-10.46L117.39-10.46Q117.60-10.84 118.02-10.94Q118.44-11.05 118.82-10.79L118.82-10.79Q119.20-10.58 119.30-10.16Q119.41-9.74 119.20-9.37L119.20-9.37Q119.15-9.32 118.88-8.90Q118.61-8.48 118.13-7.79Q117.64-7.10 116.99-6.24Q116.34-5.38 115.58-4.49L115.58-4.49Q111.68 0 108.61 0Z"
         transform="translate(50.86000366210938, 215)" />
    </g>
   </g>
  </g>
 </svg>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Realmente o css também tinha uma coisa errada, como estou a utilizar diferentes svg's, só afetava um! Obrigado

Comment: @AdrianoMaia Nesse exemplo eu coloquei uma classe direto para o elemento svg tipo: `svg { }` mas evite isso. Coloque uma classe tipo `svg.logo { }` ou um ID para o svg, assim vc evita de colocar um css que atinge os SVG que vc não quer.

Comment: sim eu sei. Queria só referir que o css tinha um erro e explicar o porquê de não ter reparado. Obrigado pelo aviso :)